# How to decide correct value of Ephemeral storage requests and limits for my pod?

Tags: kubernetes, ephemeral-storage

I am working on a'go' based application and using ephemeral-storage requests and limits in my resource yaml. I have started with requests 64Mi and limits 128Mi but is there a way to calculate the ephemeral storage requirements for a pod?. Also, if my image size is 15MiB do I need to add that also in my resource requests?.

Comment: I thought ephemeral storage refers to your ephemeral volume mounts, such as EmptyDirectory.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. My question was on is there a guideline or method to calculate the requests and limits similar to CPU/memory.

Comment: You can't calculate it. You need to figure out how much file storage you need...

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way of calculating the ephemeral storage required for a pod and this depends on how much storage you are going to use. Depending on this we can [set the right requests and limits in kubernetes](https://learnk8s.io/setting-cpu-memory-limits-requests). This document also covers how [ephemeral storage can be managed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#local-ephemeral-storage).

Comment: This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045293/how-to-determine-kubernetes-pod-ephemeral-storage-request-and-limit) also might be helpful to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**For greater visibility to the community I am posting this as a solution :**

As far as i know, there is no way of calculating the ephemeral storage required for a pod and this depends on how much storage you are going to use. Depending on this we can [set the right requests and limits in kubernetes](https://learnk8s.io/setting-cpu-memory-limits-requests). This document also covers how [ephemeral storage can be managed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#local-ephemeral-storage).

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045293/how-to-determine-kubernetes-pod-ephemeral-storage-request-and-limit) also might be helpful to your question.